# solving integro-differential equation over a square with variable boundary condition on one edge (scipy.optimize)

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, solver, boundary

I'm trying to solve a nonlinear integrodifferential equation over a square with Scipy by introducing a **variable** boundary condition on one edge of the square.

[Scipy documentation example on nonlinear solvers](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/optimize.nonlin.html) gives a sample code on how to do solve this equation, but with a set of 4 **constant** boundary conditions on each edge : P(x,1) = 1 and P=0 on any other boundary of the square [0,1]x[0,1]. That means the top edge boundary condition is P=1 and P=0 for the 3 other edges.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import newton_krylov
from numpy import cosh, zeros_like, mgrid, zeros

# Defining 2D grid of 75x75 dots :
nx, ny = 75, 75
# Defining grid steps 
hx, hy = 1./(nx-1), 1./(ny-1)
# Boundary Conditions for function P(x,y) over square [0,1]x[0,1]
P_left, P_right = 0, 0                        # P(1,y)=0 and P(0,y)=0
P_top, P_bottom = 1, 0                        # P(x,1)=1 and P(x,0)=0

# Defining integro-differential equation for function P(x,y) 
def residual(P):
    d2x = zeros_like(P)
    d2y = zeros_like(P)
    # Central Difference Approximation
    d2x[1:-1] = (P[2:]   - 2*P[1:-1] + P[:-2]) / hx/hx
    d2x[0]    = (P[1]    - 2*P[0]    + P_left)/hx/hx
    d2x[-1]   = (P_right - 2*P[-1]   + P[-2])/hx/hx
    d2y[:,1:-1] = (P[:,2:] - 2*P[:,1:-1] + P[:,:-2])/hy/hy
    d2y[:,0]    = (P[:,1]  - 2*P[:,0]    + P_bottom)/hy/hy
    d2y[:,-1]   = (P_top   - 2*P[:,-1]   + P[:,-2])/hy/hy
    # expression of the integro-differential equation
    return d2x + d2y - 10*cosh(P).mean()**2

# Defining a guess starting solution
guess = zeros((nx, ny), float)
# Iterating to find the solution 
sol = newton_krylov(residual, guess, method='lgmres', verbose=1)
print('Residual: %g' % abs(residual(sol)).max())
# visualize the solution
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x, y = mgrid[0:1:(nx*1j), 0:1:(ny*1j)]
plt.pcolor(x, y, sol)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

I want to solve the same problem, with a **variable** boundary condition on the top edge that is:

```
P_top = P(x,1) = 1/(0.5 - abs(x))
```

That means that P would have a different value on the top edge of the square, as shown on the following figure :

[image: Boundary conditions picture]

I tried to insert P_top with the formula shown on line 11 of below code but I got an error message that variable 'x' is not defined. So, I'm asking your help on how to define properly this P_top variable boundary condition in the residual.

Thanks in advance,